# Get Decimal value from XML response

Tags: xml

I know that we can get a string from XMLNode using a string and using `String invoiceNumber = root.getChildElement('invoiceNumber', null).getText();` . But I need a decimal number from same XML. can anyone please let me know the code how to get that? 
Thanks a Ton.. 
Ashok.

Comment: There's no direct method which can parse non string data from xml, as far as I can tell you. If you know the node type, you can always convert it to the required data type once you have parsed the contents.

Comment: HI @Jayant I have a list/array of decimals in that XML. I can add them to a string[] using same above syntax but I am not getting an idea how to change that string[] list to decimal. if that is a single value, then I can use valueOf(String). Can you give me a clue. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the sample xml and how you are retrieving the value?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the documentation on the various primitive types (i.e. Integer, Boolean, Decimal, etc...) you'll find that they have a `valueOf()` method that takes a string.

The decimal class is no different. From [the Decimal class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_methods_system_decimal)

> **valueOf(stringToDecimal)**
>
> Returns a Decimal that contains the value of the specified String. As in Java, the string is interpreted as representing a signed Decimal.
>
> ### Signature
>
> `public static Decimal valueOf(String stringToDecimal)`
>
> ### Parameters
>
> stringToDecimal
>       Type: String
>
> ### Return Value
>
> ```
> Type: Decimal
> ```
>
> ### Example
>
> ```
> String temp = '12.4567';
> Decimal myDecimal = Decimal.valueOf(temp);
> ```

Comment: I really appreciate your response. I am recovering from XML response body and also, the Decimal is under 4th childNode of the XML. I have almost 6 to 7 decimals of same variable and they varies. valueOf(String) can be useful but I can not use through 'child4.getElement(variable,null)' kind of coding. If there is a way, please let me know. Thank you.